# Merging two text files to one in Scilab

Tags: scilab

How to combine two text files in to a single text file in Scilab? I'm using the following code to write a text file.

```
filename = fullfile("filepath");
csvWrite(M,filename,ascii(9),".",4);
mgetl(filename);
```

One text file contain text lines while the other one contain string values. Please help me combining the two so that the text lines comes above the column string values

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand exactly what you want to do.If you want to catenate two ascii files (not binary) you can proceed as follow.
     mputl([mgetl("file1");mgetl("file2")], "file12")

If you want to form a text file from a text file  and a binary file
You have to first read the text file
    t1=mgetl("file1")
Then read the data of the binary file using the mopen, mget and mclose functions. But you must know how the data are stored in the file (integer, double, ...)

Then you have to format your data as you wish, using the string or msprintf function
to form the t2 array of strings
and finally write [t1;t2];